# has exited with code 0 (0x0) + Visual Studio c++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Hi Every one 
i got stuck with the rich text box control in visual studio 6.0, c++, while i draw this control in dialog based application it compile absolutly file but it is not able to run properly,
basically it is gets terminated automatically with the following message :

```
Loaded 'ntdll.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded symbols for 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\MFC42D.DLL'
Loaded symbols for 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCRTD.DLL'
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\gdi32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded symbols for 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\MFCO42D.DLL'
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\imm32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\secur32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\comctl32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\version.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTFIME.IME', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
The thread 0xF84 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program 'D:\test\Debug\test.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

plz look at this problem and let me solve this  why am getting stuck with this...
thankx in advance
:)

Comment: Your application exited normally, with exit code 0. You need to show code in order to get something diagnosed.

Comment: visual studio 6.0? From 1998?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot (or didn't know) to call [`AfxInitRichEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt1cfb9f.aspx) or [`AfxInitRichEdit2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6hweatz.aspx). If you use something like a `CRichEditView` this is done autoamtically, but if you embed a rich-text control in a dialog without using something like a `CRichEditView`, you need to call it.

Comment: Did you see this in the log he provided? Or do you just know this is one common pitfall? (I'm not being sarcastic i'm genuinely interested)